# string to date conversion in Unix

Tags: unix

I am using Sun Solaris unix box. 
My requirement is to convert any string  ( e.g. 21Mar2014) to date format(e.g. 20140321).

& date - d "21Mar2014" is not working in my case. It says "Illegal option -- d"

please help me in string to date conversion.

Comment: 'any string'?  You need some format restrictions!  To what date should we convert the string 'foo'?  Should we convert the string 'the day before yesterday'?  or 'four score and seven years before the third thursday of the last month that had 31 days'.

Comment: Not any string. I meant string like "21Mar2014", "01Apr2013"..

Need to convert it to some other format like 20140321

Answer (score 1):

If you have `bash`,

```
#!/bin/bash
mydate="$1"                                                   
arr=("Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec")
date=${mydate:0:2}
mon=${mydate:2:3}
year=${mydate:5:4}
i=0
for month in ${arr[@]}
do
  let i++;
  if [ "$month" == $mon ];then
      if [ "$i" -lt 10 ];then
         mon="0$i"
      fi
      break
  fi
done

echo "$date$mon$year"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there is a space between `-` and `d`. Try with `-d`, without the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 21Mar2014 | perl -MDate::Calc=Decode_Date_EU -wnE 'say Decode_Date_EU ($_)'
```

Unfortunately, that will print: `2014321`, so you'll need to work a little harder to get the right formatting:

```
echo 21Mar2014 | perl -MDate::Calc=Decode_Date_EU -wne '
    printf( "%4d%02d%02d\n", Decode_Date_EU ($_))'
```